# Why is my modded item's name not registering?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to make a mod for Minecraft (1.7.10) using forge mod loader, the details aren't particularly relevant, but basically when I attempt to create a custom item, I register the item name in a en_US.lang file. This is the code for my...

Main class

```
package com.gmx.Main;

import com.gmx.item.Succ;
import com.gmx.lib.RefStrings;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = RefStrings.MODID , name = RefStrings.NAME , version = RefStrings.VERSION )
public class MainReg {

@SidedProxy(clientSide = RefStrings.CLIENTSIDE , serverSide = RefStrings.SERVERSIDE)
public static ServerProxy proxy;

@EventHandler
public static void PreLoad(FMLPreInitializationEvent PreEvent){
    Succ.mainRegistry();
    proxy.registerRenderInfo();
}

@EventHandler
public static void load(FMLInitializationEvent event){

}

@EventHandler
public static void PostLoad(FMLPostInitializationEvent PostEvent){

}
}
```

Custom item class (Succ)

```
package com.gmx.item;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;

public class Succ {

public static void mainRegistry(){
    initializeItem();
    registerItem();
}
  public static Item genericItem;
  public static Item genericIngot;

  public static void initializeItem()
  {
          genericIngot = new Item()
                          .setMaxStackSize(16)
                          .setUnlocalizedName("genericIngot")
                          .setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabAllSearch);

  }

public static void registerItem(){
    GameRegistry.registerItem(genericIngot, "genericIngot");
}
}
```

en_US.lang file

```
item.genericIngot.name=Generic Ingot
```

The issue resides when I attempt to load a singleplayer world, The item appears as item.genericIngot.name, instead of Generic Ingot. If any addition information is needed to troubleshoot my stupidity, please leave a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
See my comment. The en_US.lang file needs to be stored in the following location in your project `src/main/resources/assets/[modid]/lang/en_US.lang`.

---

Original answer:

What you are doing looks correct except for where you do it.

Try changing this line

`public static void PreLoad(FMLPreInitializationEvent PreEvent){`

Into this:

`public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event){`

Comment: @Peter_Browning Can you confirm that your en_US.lang file is at this location `assets/[modid]/lang/en_US.lang` (obviously replace [modid] with your actual mod ID, example: `assets/petersMOD/lang/en_US.lang`).

Comment: That was the issue, I followed a guide for creating a mod for 1.6.4 as opposed to the recent 1.7.10 version, the en_US.lang file was in the incorrect location, thank you.